# How can I deploy a specific AWS Lambda function to a specific Stage

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-serverless

I have two AWS Lambda functions. I have 3 stacks dev, test, and PROD.

I want a deploy a specific the Lambda function to only dev and test but not prod.

I want the `trial` Lambda function to be only in `test` and `dev` stages but not in `PROD` stage.

How can I achieve that? Here is my `serverless.yml`:

```
service:
  name: demo-app

# Add the serverless-webpack plugin
plugins:
  - serverless-webpack
  - serverless-offline

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  timeout: 30
  stage: dev
  region: us-west-2
  profile: serverless-admin

custom:
  region: ${self:provider.region}
  stage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  prefix: ${self:service}-${self:custom.stage}
  webpack:
    webpackConfig: ./webpack.config.js
    includeModules: true

functions:
  toggle:
    handler: src/functions/unleash-toggle/handler.main
    timeout: 900
    events:
      - http:
          path: /toggle
          method: POST
  trial:
    handler: src/functions/city/handler.main
    timeout: 900
    events:
      - http:
          path: /trial
          method: POST

resources:
  Resources:
    taskTokenTable: 
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: ${self:service}-${self:custom.stage}-tokenTable
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: id
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: id
            KeyType: HASH
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
```

Comment: Now sure what you mean by "deploy a specific lambda to a specific instance". Lambda does not "work" inside of any instance, so you can't deploy it to an instance.

Comment: This question has come up several times in the past. Please use search.

Comment: @NoelLlevares I have the same question. Can you point me please to one of the previous answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research I found out this can be done.

> This can be done using serverless plugin: `serverless-plugin-ifelse` and defining your conditions under `custom` block.

you can see the same on [Serverless Docs](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-plugin-ifelse).
The plugin is available on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-plugin-ifelse)

```yaml
custom:
  serverlessIfElse:
    - If: '"${self:custom.stage}" == "prod"'
      Exclude:
        - functions.<functionName>
```

Complete `serverless.yml` file

```yaml
service:
  name: demo-app

# Add the serverless-webpack plugin
plugins:
  - serverless-webpack
  - serverless-plugin-ifelse
  - serverless-offline

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  timeout: 30
  stage: dev
  region: us-west-2
  profile: serverless-admin

custom:
  region: ${self:provider.region}
  stage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  prefix: ${self:service}-${self:custom.stage}
  webpack:
    webpackConfig: ./webpack.config.js
    includeModules: true
  serverlessIfElse:
    - If: '"${self:custom.stage}" == "prod"'
      Exclude:
        - functions.trail

functions:
  toggle:
    handler: src/functions/unleash-toggle/handler.main
    timeout: 900
    events:
      - http:
          path: /toggle
          method: POST
  trial:
    handler: src/functions/city/handler.main
    timeout: 900
    events:
      - http:
          path: /trial
          method: POST
```

> The same thing can be achieved by another plugin [serverless-plugin-conditional-functions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-plugin-conditional-functions)